# C# WPF - How to always get the current text from a textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a TextBox in FileWindow.xaml :

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="233,230,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FileName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

In ViewModel.cs:

```
public String FileName
{
    get { return _model.filename; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _model.filename)
        {
            _model.filename = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

In Model.cs:

```
private String _filename = "example.txt";
public String filename { get { return _filename; } set { _filename = value; } }
```

I want that every time I type in the TextBox, the _filename in Model.cs gets updated.
The default text in the TextBox is example.txt, but if I change it, the _filename in Model.cs doesn't change. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property of the binding to `PropertyChanged`:

```
Text="{Binding FileName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Answer (score 4):

TextBox was not immediately sent back to the source. Instead, the source was updated only after focus was lost on the TextBox. This behavior is controlled by a property on the binding called `UpdateSourceTrigger`.

It defaults to the value "Default", which basically means that the source is updated based on the property that you bind to.

Default is, obviously, the default value of the `UpdateSourceTrigger`. The other options are `PropertyChanged`, `LostFocus` and `Explicit`.

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding FileName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```